# PGF's \foreach when list requires completion

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Please is there anything I am doing wrong that PGF's `\foreach` is failing here?

```
\def\alist{}
\foreach\x in {%
  2pt_A,4pt_A,...pt_A,10pt_A
}{%
  \xdef\alist{\alist\ifx\alist\@empty\else,\fi\x}%
}
\show\alist
```

I get

```
\pgffor@dots@stripcontext #1pt_A\pgffor@@stop ->\def \pgffor@dotsvalue {#1}
Runaway argument?
10pt_A \pgffor@@stop \expandafter \pgffor@dots@charcheck \pgffor@dotsvalue \ETC
.
```

Comment: You can use `\foreach\x in {%
  2,4,...,10
}{%
  \xdef\alist{\alist\ifx\alist\@empty\else,\fi\x pt\_A}%
}`

Comment: Add a `%` (spurious space) after `10pt_A` or use `}` right there. Another point: If you initialize `\alist` to `\let\alist\pgfutil@gobble`, you can simply use `\xdef\alist{\alist,\x}` inside the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern should match exactly, one solution from the comments and one for going all the way if you want the linebreak at the end.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\alist{}
\foreach\x in {%
  2pt_A
 ,4pt_A
 ,...pt_A
 ,10pt_A
}{%
  \xdef\alist{\alist\ifx\alist\empty\else,\fi\x}%
}
\node{$\alist$};
\def\alist{}
\foreach\x in {2pt_A,4pt_A,...pt_A,10pt_A}{%
  \xdef\alist{\alist\ifx\alist\empty\else,\fi\x}%
}
\node at (0,1) {$\alist$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]