# Tikz: Failing to create node from coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-node

I'm building a tree graph and started from creating vertices

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}

\definecolor{lavander}{cmyk}{0,0.48,0,0}
\definecolor{violet}{cmyk}{0.79,0.88,0,0}
\definecolor{burntorange}{cmyk}{0,0.52,1,0}

\def\lav{lavander!90}
\def\oran{orange!30}

\tikzstyle{vertices}=[draw,circle,violet,bottom color=\lav,
                  top color= white, text=violet,minimum width=10pt]
\tikzstyle{namedvertices}=[draw,circle,burntorange, left color=\oran,
                       text=violet,minimum width=12pt]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xoffset}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yoffset}{1.5}
    % Place named vertices
    \foreach \vertex/\name in
        {
            {(0,0)/t}, 
            {(0 * \xoffset, 2 * \yoffset)/v}, 
            {(1 * \xoffset, -3 * \yoffset)/a}, 
            {(-4 * \xoffset, -4 * \yoffset)/u}, 
            {(0 * \xoffset, -4 * \yoffset)/b}
        }
        \node[namedvertices] (\name) at \vertex {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, compiling this i'm getting

> Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.

in the line of last vertex. And the result looks like
[image]

If i remove just the last vertex, i.e. stay with 4 instead of 5, everything compiles fine.

> What am I doing wrong? Or what should i change in order to handle more than 4 nodes?

**Update:** I've solved the problem by doing

```
{(0 * \xoffset, -4 * \yoffset)/b}%
```

So maybe now,

> I want to understand why it solved something? Initially no hidden symbols were written after the closing } in the first place.

Comment: In your `foreach` tha first `\vertex` is set to `{(0,0)/t}` and your `\name` is empty. You should delete `{}` or keep them like this `{(0,0)}/t`.

Comment: Why it didn't affect me when i've used numbers instead of \offset's?

Comment: Into the list of the `\foreach`, add `%` just after the last `}`:  [...]`* \yoffset)/b}%`

Comment: @Kpym, evidently (after i started adding edges) your solution is not working - it claims b is not known, reversing to the }% solution indeed solves. Strange.

Comment: Yes, as @PaulGaborit says, you have to add `%` after the last one to remove the white spaces (new line). But in any case you do not need all this `{}`.

Comment: It really looks like a "bug"... Compare `\foreach\sa/\sb in{{a/b} }{\typeout{1:\sa,2:\sb}}` and `\foreach\sa/\sb in{{a/b}}{\typeout{1:\sa,2:\sb}}` .  _Space_ is important!

Answer (score 4):

TikZ works by parsing the input stream via looking for patterns. And a brace pair `{}` is to group the input arguments. When you are bracing the items, you basically make them a single argument for vertex.

When TikZ sees `at` it switches to coordinate parsing mode and it (note that it strips the braces because they are the input to the foreach macro) and finds the parenthesis `(` now it takes everything until the first `)` as the coordinate expression and the rest is left in the input stream namely `/b` and because inside TikZ environment `\nullfont` is on nothing that TikZ don't care gets printed. That's why `b` is not taken as the name of the node because it is thrown away.

Regarding the `%` issue, again TikZ decides on the loop array by comparing things literally even to the whitespaces and a linebreak is a whitespace character. A similar issue can be seen here [PGF's \foreach when list requires completion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114239/pgfs-foreach-when-list-requires-completion). Hence this works:

```
\draw (b ) -- (a);% Notice the whitespace after b
```

A good practice is to avoid bracing multiparameter foreach patterns, or bracing each item in the `../../..` stream individually.